# fixed position div is no longer fixed to the bottom after AngularJS ng-show

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, css-position, ng-show

Here my issue :
I have a div with the id "foo" :

```
#foo {
    position:fixed !important;
    bottom:0 !important;
    left:0;
    ...
}
```

And its animation of collapse : (please don't link me bootstrap-ui ...)

```
#foo.ng-hide-add, #foo.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    display:block!important;
}

#foo.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
#foo.ng-hide-remove {
    height:0;
}

#foo.ng-hide-add,
#foo.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    height:170px;
}
```

And finaly a directive :

```
<pp-foo collap="foo.collapsed"></pp-foo>
```

which bind a boolean named foo.collapsed

```
<div id="foo" ng-hide="collap">
...
</div>
```

The animation is rendered perfectly but the div foo is no longer fixed on the bottom after a hide/show. It's in the middle of the page.

Should have reset bottom to 0 in angular controller ?

Should have used angular.animation directly to get more handling ?

Any idea ?